# How can I invert my display colours under Kubuntu?

Tags: 10.10, gnome, kde, color-management

I installed the KDE graphical interface to run alongside GNOME for my 10.10 installation.  For the most part, it seems to work well, and the extra eye candy is appealing.  However, there is one thing that is bugging me, and that is color inversion.

In GNOME, all I have to do is press the <kbd>Win</kbd>-<kbd>N</kbd> keys and the application window inverts colors.  This is especially useful when reading text, since I find it much easier on the eyes to read white on black text.

However, this combination doesn't work in Kubuntu.  Is there a hack or workaround existing so I can have this functionality in both window managers?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Open SystemSettings (from the K > Computer menu). Go to Desktop Effects then in the All Effects tab you'll see the top item in accessibility is "invert". It should be easy enough, tick the checkbox, set your preferred hotkeys (default Ctrl+Meta+I or Ctrl+Meta+U to change only the selected window) and voila.

Edit: added shortcuts, answer correct as of 2022-02-06.

Comment: Where does this live in kubuntu 18.04? I don't see it. I found it in Desktop Effects in more current releases.